# ANDROID SQLITE check if table has data

Tags: android, sqlite

I'd like to check if my table has records. Here's what I've tried:

```
if( cursor != null ){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getInt(0) == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No records yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Logcat says:

```
  CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: test the result of moveToFirst, or of cursor.getCount (that how many records are in your cursor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
cursor.getCount();
```

it will return if cursor retrieve data count if this give 0 then there is no data

so

```
if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount()>0){
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   //do your action
   //Fetch your data

}
else {
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No records yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Note : even though you check `if( cursor != null )` cursor will not return null value after doing any query, so do this to check the data count in cursor after that

Answer (score 0):

`Cursor.getCount()` will return 0 for an empty result set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the method `getCount()`.

Just check `cursor.getCount()==0` for empty result.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
//do your work
}
else{
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No records yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```