# Passing data from SQLite database using Intent

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, android-intent

In my app I have an SQLite database and I want to know how to transfer some of the data such as id, title etc to another activity.

This is my code so far:

```
ListView lv = getListView();

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) 
    {
        onListItemClick(v,pos,id);
    }
    protected void onListItemClick(View v, int pos, long id) 
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Table.class);
        i.putExtra("Value1", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title")));
        startActivity(i); 

    }
});
```

but i am getting errors.

```
01-29 12:25:46.511: E/AndroidRuntime(26478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 12:25:46.511: E/AndroidRuntime(26478): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 50 requested, with a size of 50
01-29 12:25:46.511: E/AndroidRuntime(26478):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
01-29 12:25:46.511: E/AndroidRuntime(26478):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
01-29 12:25:46.511: E/AndroidRuntime(26478):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
01-29 12:25:46.511: E/AndroidRuntime(26478):    at com.example.studentdatabase.MainActivity$2.onListItemClick(MainActivity.java:90)
01-29 12:25:46.511: E/AndroidRuntime(26478):    at com.example.studentdatabase.MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:87)
01-29 12:25:46.511: E/AndroidRuntime(26478):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
01-29 12:25:46.511: E/AndroidRuntime(26478):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
01-29 12:25:46.511: E/AndroidRuntime(26478):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
01-29 12:25:46.511: E/AndroidRuntime(26478):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-29 12:25:46.511: E/AndroidRuntime(26478):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-29 12:25:46.511: E/AndroidRuntime(26478):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-29 12:25:46.511: E/AndroidRuntime(26478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-29 12:25:46.511: E/AndroidRuntime(26478):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 12:25:46.511: E/AndroidRuntime(26478):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-29 12:25:46.511: E/AndroidRuntime(26478):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-29 12:25:46.511: E/AndroidRuntime(26478):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-29 12:25:46.511: E/AndroidRuntime(26478):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: what type of error you are getting ?

Comment: can you post detailed log cat ?

Comment: in eclipse window -> show view -> logcat.  and copy lines which marked as error (i mean i red color ) and post it

Comment: Post the entire class please, hard to see what is going on from just this piece of code.

Comment: I think error related to database (your cursor is beyound end of record), can you post your full code ?

Answer (score 0):

The code that you put is not what's wrong here. It's where your Cursor is pointing. After your Cursor declaration you should call moveToFirst().

```
cursor.moveToFirst()
```

Comment: Then you need to show us more code. Preferable the code inside the `onListItemClick()` in `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

you must point the position on cursor

```
cursor.moveToFirst()
```

also try to validate data in cursor to avoid further exception. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14566988/1450401)