# Method query db to return results

Tags: android, sqlite

App won't run. This occurs recurrently:

```
04-05 21:29:09.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1069): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
   Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  
   The statement has 0 parameters.
```

Main - Calling method

```
Cursor wow = db.trying("Gold");
       text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
       String quantity = wow.getString(0); //
       text.setText(quantity);
```

DB Handler - Method

```
public Cursor trying(String vg){
        String q = "SELECT quantity FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE name=" + "'" + vg +"'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor  cursor = db.rawQuery(q, new String[] {vg});

            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return cursor;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why you created next question instead of refer this error in previous one and give me next comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
 String q = "SELECT quantity FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE name=" + "'" + vg +"'";
```

In your query you had already specify the parameter for where condition .After that you are again passing it to query

```
Cursor  cursor = db.rawQuery(q, new String[] {vg});
```

This makes the confusion .So try to change your query

```
String q = "SELECT quantity FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE name = ?";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor  cursor = db.rawQuery(q, new String[] {vg});
```

OR you go for another approach

```
   String q = "SELECT quantity FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " WHERE name=" + "'" + vg +"'";
    Cursor  cursor = db.rawQuery(q, null);
   if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount()>0){
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   //do your action
   //Fetch your data

}
else {
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No records yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14566988/1450401)